# Does a syntax highlighter in an IDE scan the whole file every time a letter is typed?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, token, lexical-analysis

Assuming a syntax highlighter uses a lexer to do the background work: when typing in an IDE with live syntax highlighting, does the lexer have to re-tokenize the entire file (in whatever language, ex. Java, C++, Python, etc), does the lexer only have to re-read and tokenize the current line, or does it only keep itself occupied with a single character/word at a time?

I'm asking because in a lot of editors/IDEs, most code remains the same as the programmer is typing, however, in some cases there's stuff like starting a string literal, which re-highlights the rest of the line, and in other cases like starting a multi-line comment, the whole text file becomes re-highlighted from the point where I start the multi-line comment, to the end of the file.

If the lexical analysis has to be done for the entire file for every single letter typed, wouldn't that make it slow, especially for larger (100.000+ lines) text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax highlight and semantic highlight.

Syntax highlight is when editor only decorates based on language syntax - e.g. identifiers are black, keywords are pink and comments are green. Syntax highlight does not necessarily reparses (or, rather, tokenizes) the whole file - it can only tokenize "damaged region" (e.g. tokens around edit location). Of course, editor developer may opt to tokenize the whole input - as it is really fast, error-proof and easier to implement.

Semantic highlight (one that, for instance, can highlight global and local identifiers differently) usually require complete reparse - e.g. in Java adding "static" to function declaration would require you to invalidate function references both above and below the cursor. In some cases caching may be implemented (e.g. cache include files parse result as user edit does not change it that much). Semantic highlight is slow so it is usually combined with syntax highligh (you may see in Eclipse that the keywords are highlighted instantly - while member variable changes the color from the black after some small delay).

Comment: So in your opinion (or based on facts), would having a Syntax Highlight re-tokenize the entire file on every single input character, be a bad idea? I'm just wondering what an editor like Notepad++ does, to give an example.

Comment: For me, this is a tradeoff between speed and implementation complexity. E.g. the smarter you are trying to be, the more obscure bugs you will find. Tokenizing is really fast, hence often you just update the whole input. Then you won't face odd artifacts when you need to support another language. You also may not do the highlighting on every keypress - e.g. wait for the token end (character that is not a part of the "word") or when the user pauses typing. Of course, you should benchmark the tokenizing so the user typing experience is not impacted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Notepad++. Some C/C++ extensions for Sublime and Vim, for instance, use libclang - this reparses the whole "translation unit" (edited file + includes) though it does perform some caching.

Comment: Well, no, I basically just need simple keyword highlighting for now (although it might be expanded to something more complex), so whether it's C/C++/Java/Python/C# or whatever, I don't need to go further beyond than the current file, and caching is the furthest thing from my mind. As for Notepad++, it does basically highlight the second you type something that might be considered a keyword. Typing "void" will immediately result in a highlighted word, but add an extra letter like "voids", and it immediately de-colors. Would re-tokenizing 100.000 lines every 1/5th of a second be too demanding?

Comment: It might not be too demanding - you just profile and then decide. It is not often that you see source files 100,000 lines long. Note that tokenizer does not need context information - so you can use same tokenizer implementation on the whole file and on arbitrary region of the file (but region should include whole tokens).

Comment: The problem with dirty region is that you need to decide on region boundaries (there may be edge cases and language-specific issues - e.g. line edited might be in a comment so your region should contain the whole comment, some languages have multi-line strings, etc.), will need to properly merge highlight regions information, etc. It may not be that computationally simpler as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll first implement syntax highlighting which rereads the entire text every time a letter is typed, and then I think I'll implement some form of region restriction (maybe make it line-based, except when a token appears to involve multiple lines, the only issue being the possibility of a bug ruining the layout). It's not like I'm making the new Vim after all, it's only something I want to do for the sake of just doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look this up, but I am pretty sure that it depends what is being highlighted. That is, comparing the local area you are typing in with basic syntax; versus, say an open comment that until closed highlights from that point until the end of the file.